Java HashMap iteration order - behavior seems consistent despite documentation stating otherwise
I'm learning about HashMaps in Java and I'm confused about the iteration order. The documentation states that HashMap doesn't guarantee any specific iteration order, but in my simple test, the order seems to remain consistent:

This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. Java 11 Docs

import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> dishes = new HashMap<>();

        // Adding more elements with complex keys
        dishes.put("dish-1234", "Pho");
        dishes.put("dish-5678", "Spicy Beef Noodle Soup");
        dishes.put("dish-9012", "Broken Rice");
        dishes.put("dish-3456", "Banh Mi");
        dishes.put("dish-7890", "Hu Tieu");
        dishes.put("dish-2345", "Mi Quang");
        dishes.put("dish-6789", "Crab Noodle Soup");
        dishes.put("dish-0123", "Rolled Rice Cake");

        System.out.println("First time:");
        dishes.forEach((id, name) -> System.out.println(id + ": " + name));

        // Create new HashMap with same data
        HashMap<String, String> dishes2 = new HashMap<>();
        dishes2.putAll(dishes);

        System.out.println("\nSecond time (New HashMap):");
        dishes2.forEach((id, name) -> System.out.println(id + ": " + name));
    }
}

Output:
First time:
dish-7890: Hu Tieu
dish-3456: Banh Mi
dish-2345: Mi Quang
dish-1234: Pho
dish-0123: Rolled Rice Cake
dish-5678: Spicy Beef Noodle Soup
dish-9012: Broken Rice
dish-6789: Crab Noodle Soup

Second time (New HashMap):
dish-7890: Hu Tieu
dish-3456: Banh Mi
dish-2345: Mi Quang
dish-1234: Pho
dish-0123: Rolled Rice Cake
dish-5678: Spicy Beef Noodle Soup
dish-9012: Broken Rice
dish-6789: Crab Noodle Soup

I understand that if I need guaranteed order, I should use LinkedHashMap or TreeMap, but I'm trying to understand the actual behavior of HashMap. I read some documentation talk about re-size and re-hashing, maybe it's too hard to understand for me.
I also read some post say this problem, but I can not re-produce

Why HashMap does not guarantee that the order of the map will remain constant over time
Cause of the difference in the insertion order of HashMap and LinkedHashMap

How can I understand this?

it also makes no guarantees that the order will change over time; and you have not tested all implementations neither did you cover ALL time -- probably (not guaranteed) you will get the same content if the map is created the same way

example where inserting an element ("seven") changes the output order: IDEone inserting up to "six" does not change the order of previous elements (relative to each other, maybe the new element is inserted (in iterator order) between two existing ones, but after inserting "seven" the order of previous elements is changed (e.g. "four" and "one" were last , moved to 2nd and 3rd position) - certainly additional buckets were created

or this ! Same content iterated in different order after adding and removing the same element (based on previous example)

The fact that there are no guarantees as to the order of the map does not prohibit some examples from being consistent with each other. The "no guarantees" clause is a warning you should not depend on consistency.

Try making this change: HashMap<String, String> dishes2 = new HashMap<>(2000);

Behavior may vary

trying to understand the actual behavior of HashMap

You are trying to understand the internal implementation details of HashMap.  Don’t.
Whatever behavior you may observe, that behavior may vary.

The behavior may vary at runtime. The implementation programmers may have written the behavior to change depending on the quantity of elements, or their types, or their content. The iteration order may even change each time you loop through the map.
The behavior may vary with any new release. The programmers are free to change their implementation at any time, as long as they comply with the contract promised in the Javadoc.

The Javadoc is the contract
If the Javadoc says you cannot count on a particular order, then do not depend on a particular order.
If the Javadoc does not promise thread-safety, then do not expect thread-safety.
The Javadoc is the formal contract, the agreement between you and the implementation programmers. Do not make assumptions, do not use your intuition. What you read in the Javadoc describes the expected behavior. Anything beyond the Javadoc may exist, may not exist, or may vary, but should never be expected by you.
SequencedMap
For a particular order, use an implementation of SequencedMap. Implementations bundled with Java: ConcurrentSkipListMap, LinkedHashMap, and TreeMap. To learn about the Sequenced Collections API added to Java 21, read JEP 431, and see excellent talk by Stuart Marks.
Java offers two other ordered map interfaces: NavigableMap (Java 6+) and  SortedMap (Java 2+), both implemented by two of those three classes named above: ConcurrentSkipListMap and TreeMap.
Consider using TreeMap first, if thread-safety is not a concern. Very large amounts of data may perform better with ConcurrentSkipListMap.

Mermaid coding:
---
title: Java Map hierarchy
---
classDiagram
    Map <|-- SequencedMap
    SequencedMap <|-- SortedMap
    SortedMap <|-- NavigableMap
    NavigableMap <|-- ConcurrentNavigableMap
    NavigableMap <|.. TreeMap : implements
    ConcurrentNavigableMap <|.. ConcurrentSkipListMap : implements
    SequencedMap <|.. LinkedHashMap : implements
    class Map { <<interface>> }
    class SequencedMap { <<interface>> }
    class NavigableMap { <<interface>> }
    class SortedMap { <<interface>> }
    class ConcurrentNavigableMap { <<interface>> }
    class TreeMap { }
    class ConcurrentSkipListMap { }
    class LinkedHashMap { }

Third-parties
You may find third-party implementations of ordered maps, such as in Google Guava or Eclipse Collections.
Curiosity
If curiosity drives you to learn about the implementation details of HashMap, learn the basic concepts such as at Wikipedia, then study the open source code on GitHub.

This is explainable.  First some relevant facts:

You are using a key type (String) that has a hashCode method whose algorithm is specified, and that is guaranteed to give the same hashcode value for all runs1.

You are inserting the same key / value pairs in precisely the same order each time.


Given the above, the implementation of HashMap that you are using is going to give you a consistent order for the keys.  If you were prepared to analyze the source code, you would be able to see why.
However, this is an artifact of the current implementation ... and the way that you are using it.

If you switched to a different JVM with a different HashMap implementation, you might get a different ordering.  (Especially if you inserted many more distinct keys.)

If you changed the key to a type whose hashCode could be different for different runs, then the ordering would be different.  For example, if you used StringBuffer instead of String2.



What your real mistake is here is a misunderstanding of what the javadoc is saying.   When it says "this class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map", it is not saying that the ordering WILL be inconsistent.  What it is saying is that it COULD be inconsistent.
Note that "could be inconsistent" logically implies "could be consistent".
So the fact that you have found a scenario where you (appear to3) get a consistent order is not surprising.  And it doesn't contradict the javadoc!

1 - Indeed, the algorithm is the same for all versions of Java.
2 - This is for demo purposes only: it is the wrong thing to do for other reasons.
3 - Your test is not sufficient to show that your platform will give consistent orderings if, for example, the keys are dynamic, or there are a huge number of key value pairs, or the insertions are done in a different sequence.

Here is some explenation on what goes on under the hood.

The insertion of elements in a HashMap is not dependent on the order in which they are added. Instead, it relies on the hash code of the key and the availability of slots in the map’s internal array.
If the computed slot for a key is already occupied (due to a hash collision), the HashMap resolves this by either chaining or probing. This resolution process does not preserve insertion order and can involve traversing or modifying multiple slots.
When the map’s capacity is exceeded, a new, larger map is created, and all existing entries are rehashed and redistributed. This rehashing process ignores the original insertion order entirely.


First of all hash maps is a standard computer science data structure. There are variations, but it is worthwhile looking into Wikipedia and such.
The data structure HashMap (in java) uses fixed sized buckets (arrays) in which the items are stored by an index being the item's hash key modulo the array size. When two different items collide by getting the same index rehashing must be done, a next index taken. This means that with growing hash maps restructuring of the buckets may happen. Hence:

Over time the order is not guaranteed.

You could artificially keep filling a HashMap till the item order starts changing. After some addition the order will fail.
For instance (untested):
List<String> order = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (;;) {
    key = ... read from dictionary 
    String oldKey = map.put(key, value):
    if (oldKey == null) {
        // Time to check the order:
        List<String> nextOrder = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
        for (int i = 0; i < nextOrder.size(); ++i) {
            if (i == order.size() || !order.get(i).equals(nextOrder.get(i)) {
                if (nextOrder.get(i).equals(key)) {
                    orders.add(i, key);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Order changed");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }

